# repainting the image using bufferedimage

Tags: java

i am learning to write code in java and recently started to write a game as per my assignment.
i have completed almost entire game but stuck with the animation part of the game.
here is what i have done so far,

this is the class that load the image ti display,

```
public class dpmImage {
    private BufferedImage dpm1;
    private BufferedImage setDpm1;


    public dpmImage() { //this is a constructor
        try {
            dpm1= ImageIO.read(new File("dpm1Load.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setDpm1 = dpm1;
    }

    private BufferedImage dpm1ImageGet() {
        return setDpm1;
    }

}
```

the following code is from main class (Main.java)

```
private Graphics cGraphcs;
cGraphcs.drawImage(dpmImageInstance.dpm1ImageGet(), 0, 0, null);
```

The code is working fine and displays the image.
Now, I am allowed to modify anything in `dpmImage` class but not allowed to modify anything in `Main.java` and still make this image animate. So I create an array of `BufferedImage` in `dpmImage` class and add a second image in the array as follows,

```
public class dpmImage {
    private BufferedImage [] dpm1 = new BufferedImage[2];
    private BufferedImage setDpm1;


    public dpmImage() { //this is a constructor
        try {
            dpm1[0]= ImageIO.read(new File("dpm1Load.png"));
            dpm1[1]= ImageIO.read(new File("dpm1Load1.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setDpm1 = dpm1[0];
        setDpm1 = dpm1[1];
    }

    private BufferedImage dpm1ImageGet() {
        return setDpm1;
    }

}
```

But i couldn't get to animate it from first image to 2nd. Can someone please give me any hints on that ? i am not allowed to change the `Main.java` class

Comment: Well, you have an array but you initiaize `setDpm1` twice, so and up with `dpm1[1]`. You might want to be able to return either `dpm1[0]` or `dpm1[1]` based on something.

Answer (score 0):

You always return the same `BufferedImage` from the `dpm1ImageGet` method. You need to get the instance from the array. Based on the frequency of the update, you can simply use an index like

```
private int indexImage = 0;

private BufferedImage dpm1ImageGet() {
    indexImage = ( indexImage + 1 ) % dpm1.length; //increment and use % to prevent any ArrayOutOfBoundsException
    return dpm1[indexImage];
}
```

Each call will return the next image. Of course, this depends on when you want to get the other image. It could be anything.